# Do NIC drivers change descriptor ring algorithms on different socket buffer sizes?

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

[image]

If I set a socket buffer size to a particular max,
will this affect the way the network card uses its descriptor ring?

```
int option = 4800;
setsockopt(socket_id, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char *)&nSocketOption, sizeof(nSocketOption);
```

**Are the sectors of the ring different sizes based on my decision to set the socket's buffer size?**

---

The reason I ask, is because I'm receiving multiple messages over the same socket.  A size of `4,800` bytes, should be able to hold about 25 messages, before dropping packets.  Doing a size of `4,800` results in the smallest message being processed as frequently as its being sent (about 17 times a second).  But when I change the socket buffer size to `4,799`, all of my small packets get dropped.

I believe this is due to the network card processing differently based on the buffer size.
Is this a fair assumption?

Comment: Interesting question. May I know the source of that kernel diagram - thanks.

Comment: @artm http://beyond-syntax.com/blog/2011/03/diving-into-linux-networking-i/

Comment: No, that's not a fair assumption. The nic  ring buffer is decoupled from your socket buffers, influencing it based on a single socket doesn't make much sense as network stack design accounts for there there's many sockets.